# Goodness of fit for discrete data: best approach

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit

**The data:**
For the purposes of this question/communication we can assume the data looks like `rnbinom(1000,size=0.1,prob=0.01)` in R, which generates a random sample of 1,000 observations from a negative binomial distribution (with `size=0.1` and probability of success `prob=0.01`). This is the parametrization where the random variable represents the number of failures before `size` number of successes. The tail is long, and 1,000 observations is not a lot of data.

**The problem:**
I have been given some data (integer on {1,2,....}) [see above] (1,500 data points) and asked to find "best fit" distribution and estimates of any parameters. I know nothing else about the data. I'm aware I this is not a very large sample for data with a long tail. More data is a possibility.

**What I've done:**
I have considered using a likelihood ratio test by fitting two different distributions to the data, but I don't think this applies (as in, I cannot determine appropriate critical p-values) unless the two distributions are nested...

I then considered using a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (adjusted for discrete data) but, in R anyway, it complained it could not compute a p-value for "data with ties".

What is the best way for me to go about testing/determining the fit of different distributions in this context?
Here are some other things I have considered:

1. Ask for (lots) more data. But will this help? Will I be able to use asymptotic results, for instance?
2. Consider some bootstrap/re-sampling/monte-carlo scheme? If so, is there a standard reference I can/should read to learn how to do this correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you just need to **fit data to distribution**. In this case, you could use one of functions in R packages, such as `fitdistr` from `MASS` package, which uses *maximum likelihood estimation (MLE)* and supports *discrete distributions*, including *binomial* and *Poisson*.

Then, as a second step, you would need to perform one (or more) of *goodness-of-fit (GoF)* tests to **validate results**. *Kolmogorov-Smirnov*, *Anderson-Darling* and (AFAIK) *Lilliefors* tests all are not applicable to discrete distributions. However, fortunately, **chi-square GoF test** is applicable to both continuous and discrete distributions and in R is a matter of calling `stats::chisq.test()` function.

**Alternatively**, as your data represents a discrete distribution, you can use `vcd` package and its function `goodfit()`. This function can be used either as a replacement for standard GoF test `chisq.test()`, or, even better, as a **full workflow** (*distribution fitting* and *GoF testing*). For the *full workflow* option, just use default setup and do not specify parameters `par` (you can specify `size`, if `type = "nbinomial"`). The parameters will be estimated, using *maximum likelihood* or *minimum chi-square* (you can select the method). Results can be obtained by calling `summary()` function.

Comment: Discrete KS tests do exist in fact: http://www.stat.yale.edu/~jay/EmersonMaterials/DiscreteGOF.pdf