# Testing if Binomial Data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, binomial-distribution

Suppose that I have the following data: $4,0,4,2,1,8,4,1,3,3,5,4,6,1,3$. How do we check if the data comes from a binomial distribution, say Bin($p,8$) for some $p$ or from some other distribution on $\{0,1,\dots, 8\}$? Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: Though I know a bit of statistics, I do not have a stat background (but math background!).

Comment: Where did your value of $n=8$ come from?  Was it estimated as the largest of the data values or did you know it beforehand?

Comment: @whuber Yes, it was just estimated as the largest of the data values.

Comment: Do you know if the success probability is the same for all fifteen of the binomial trials? That is, could one be $\text{Binomial}(8, 0.2)$ while another is $\text{Binomial}(8,0.9)?$

Comment: Perhaps start with theory: how are you expecting the data to be generated? For example, if you have a fixed number of trials of which can be success or failure, binomial data may be appropriate. If it's the count of trials until a success, a geometric. If it's a counting process of some kind, Poisson or Negative Binomial.

Failing that, you may be able to use the R function `fitdist` to fit a variety of distributions and assess which looks best.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, we know that the given sample is i.i.d. Sorry, I should have mentioned this in the problem.

Comment: @AlexJ: I understand that what you say could be a practical solution in such a situation. However, what I'm looking for is, whether there's is any theory that deals the hypothesis testing problem in my question.

Comment: When you have to estimate $n$ and $n$ is larger than $3$ or so, typically you need a *huge* sample size, because the Binomial distributions with parameters $(n,p)$ and $(n^\prime,p^\prime)$ where $np = n^\prime p^\prime$ are almost indistinguishable -- and become ever closer as $n$ and $n^\prime$ increase.  This is one reason we need the specifics of your actual problem in order to supply workable answers.

Comment: @whuber: In our problem $n$ is known. We know that the distribution has support $\{0,1,\dots, 8\}$. All we want to test is, whether it is Bin($8,p$) for some $p$ or some other distribution on $\{0,1,\dots, 8\}$.

Comment: Ashok You have completely confused me, because when I asked you whether it was estimated or known, your answer was "it was just estimated as the largest of the data values."  Has that changed??  If $n$ is known, just apply the standard textbook chi-squared test.

Comment: @whuber: When I say "n is known", I mean 'n is assumed known' (actually I took the largest of the data values). Btw, this n does not necessarily mean the binomial parameter n. All we know is that the underlying distribution, say $P$ is something that has support $\{0,1,\dots, 8\}$. Now the problem is to test if $P$ is Bin($8,p$) for some $p$ or some other distribution on $\{0,1,\dots, 8\}$. Hope it is clear now. Does the usual 'chi-square test' address this problem?

Comment: "Taking the largest of the data values" is an *estimate* of $n$ (and might be a poor one).  You *don't* know the support is limited at  $8$ if this is an estimate.  The usual chi-squared test will not produce correct p-values in this case unless the estimate is accurate.  In your example the likelihood is maximized only in the limit as $n$ grows arbitrarily large and your estimate $\hat n = 8$ is not even within a 95% confidence interval.

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123367/estimating-parameters-for-a-binomial/123748#123748   and  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219200/mle-for-the-binomial-distributed-data-number-of-boys-in-families/453210#453210